# PostgreSQL: Difference between 2 timestamps in days, hours and minutes

Tags: postgresql

I have two timestamps and I need to calculate the difference between them in Days:Hours:Minutes.

I have done timestamp2-timestamp1 and the result is in months, days, hours and minutes. How can I convert the months in days knowing that some months have 31 days and the rest 30 without losing precision.

Comment: Subtracting two timestamps will always produce an interval in days, hours, minutes and seconds. How did you get it to give you months?

Comment: I had to use justify_interval, because I had to sum timesstamp1-timestamp2 and timestamp3-timestamp4. So the interval wasn´t justified.

Comment: Just don't justify the intervals, then there is no problem.

Comment: The thing is that the hours and minutes have to be justified, but the days can be more than 30 or 31. For example 45 days  23 hours  14 min.

Comment: That's exactly what you get if you subtract timestamps. Or can you show a counter-example?

Comment: Yes that´s true. The problem is that I have to sum two differences of timestamps. So if the first is 20 days, 20 hours 20 min and the second is 40 days 15 hours 50 min. When I sum them the result is 60 days 35 hours 70 minutes and the hours and minutes wouldn´t be justified.

Comment: Use `justify_hours` on the interval difference.

Comment: justify_hours worked! Thanks man! PD: I don´t know how can I give u points or somehing.